# Videojs - how to add a custom icon in the control bar

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio, video.js

I am using the videojs library to build a player audio.
I would like to add the custom component, such as an image, in the control bar, before the play button.

I read how to add a custom button:

```
var button = videojs.getComponent('Button');
var closeButton = videojs.extend(button, {
    constructor: function() {
        button.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    /*  handleClick: function() {
        this.player().dispose();
    }*/
});
```

But it doesn't work to add image.
Somebody can help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpRZBe

Answer (score 4):

For an image you can add a Component, which creates a div, and add a class to style it.

```
<script>
  videojs('my_video').ready(function() {
    var img = this.controlBar.addChild('Component', {}, 0); // 3rd arg is index, i.e. first
    img.addClass("my-image");
  });
</script>
<style>
  .video-js .my-image {
    width: 40px;
    background: url(https://placekitten.com/38/28) center center no-repeat;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Note :** This is tested in the latest version of videojs as of now (v7.15.0)

As per documentations at : https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-components.html#creating-a-component, we will first create a VideoJS Button component and create our button instance that is to be added to the control bar.

**Get the video js instance :**

`var player = videojs(document.querySelector('#videoJsPlayer'))`

Next let us **create the Button component and add a button** to our videojs player instance :

```
      var ButtonComp = videojs.getComponent('Button');
      var notesBut = new ButtonComp(player, {
        clickHandler: function(event) {
          videojs.log('Custom Button Clicked');
          //Perform your logic here !
        }
      });
```

We will **add a custom class** so that we can access this particular button and add out icon and hence append our custom Button to the controlBar

```
     notesBut.addClass('addNotesBut')
     player.controlBar.addChild(notesBut,{},3)
     console.log(notesBut.contentEl());
```

Here I add my button to 3rd Index that means 4th position.
The console shows the following **output :**

```
    <button class="vjs-control vjs-button addNotesBut" type="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="vjs-icon-placeholder"></span>
        <span class="vjs-control-text" aria-live="polite"></span>
    </button>
```

Note that we will **add our icon** to the vjs-icon-placeholder of the newly created button. We access it via classes and insert out icon as shown below. I have added a Bootstrap Icon and used its SVG. You can play around with different HTML Tags like  or .

```
document.querySelector('.addNotesBut .vjs-icon-placeholder').innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-journal-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1.5H10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V10a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8.5H6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h1.5V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/><path d="M3 0h10a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-1h1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h10a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H3a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1H1V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2z"/><path d="M1 5v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1zm0 3v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V8h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1zm0 3v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1z"/></svg>'
```

And thus this is how you can add custom Icon to VideoJS.